# ListView добавить цвет каждому пункту и запомнить

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `String[] colors` и GridView, каждому пункту я задаю цвет.

Вопрос в том, как сделать так, что бы каждый пункт помнил свой цвет после листания GridView?

```
private String[] colors = null;
colors = new String[] {"#4BBEBA","#69CCE3","#7277C1","#ffffDD","#FACE4C","#EF6960","#E63F84","#2F6175","#444646"};
LinearLayout mainLayout;
mainLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lineartext);
mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[position]));`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно:

1. Хранить в адаптере массив/список цветов для каждого элемента списка/таблицы.
2. В методе отрисовки элемента (`getView()`) устанавливать цвет его по позиции.

Так цвета элементов будут сохраняться при пересоздании оных.

Comment: вапрос как в getview вапрос как в добавить цвет по позиции ?

Comment: mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorsB[position])); но цветов меньше чем пунктов

Comment: @DavidKern, значит вам надо сделать в адаптере список цветов, равный по длине списку элементов.

Comment: @DavidKern вам нужно сохранить значения цвета в каждой позиции, а не массив доступных цветов. Может быть вообще два цвета и сотни пунктов - вы сохраняете, что в позиции 1 - цвет1, в позиции 2 - цвет1, в позиции 3 - цвет2, в позиции 4 - цвет1 и тд.

Comment: но если  что в позиции 100  - цвет 8 проблема в том што рзмеры массива и getview разные